# How to customize the colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

Using this code, I don't know how to customize the colorbar. The colormaps on this [webiste](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) can't satisfy me.

```
shade = m.contourf(Lon,Lat,TBB,np.arange(-90, -20, 10),extend='both',cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet'))       
m.colorbar(shade)
```

[image: my_colorbar]

I want to draw a picture like this with obvious colorbar. So, what should I do?
     [image: colorbar]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define your own colormap using `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap()` or `matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap()` and use it for your plot.

Example:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

x = np.arange(0,25)
a = np.random.randint(0,130, size=(25,25))-115
a = np.sort(a).reshape(25,25)

colors = ["#eaa941", "#efef39", "#53a447", "#3b387f", "#48a2ba"]
cmap= matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
cmap.set_under("crimson")
cmap.set_over("w")
norm= matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=-100,vmax=-0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.contourf(x,x,a, levels=[-100,-80,-60,-40,-20,0],
                 extend='both',cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

fig.colorbar(im, extend="both")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `colors = ["#eaa941", "#efef39", "#53a447", "#3b387f", "#48a2ba"]
cmap= matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
cmap.set_under("crimson")
cmap.set_over("w")
norm= matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=-80,vmax=-30)
shade=m.contourf(Lon,Lat,TBB,extend='both',cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
m.colorbar(shade)` Then, I get this [picture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzCLPN5o3ziHWEotTTl5U2o3TEk), why?

Comment: You would also need to define the levels in the contouf plot. I upated the answer to actually use a contouf plot.

Comment: Your answer is ture. But, I want to add the color on the map. So, I try this code: `im = m.contourf(Lon,Lat,TBB,levels=[-80,-70,-60,-50,-40,-30],extend='both',cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
m.colorbar(im)` and other codes are as same as yours. It works fine and the picture is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzCLPN5o3ziHMVNUalR4ZzFpUVE).

Comment: is there a way to merge the colors and not have discrete colors?

Comment: @RitambharaChauhan The concept of a contour plot is to have discrete levels. Obviously, if you take enough levels plot may look more continuous than discrete.

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like the `spectral` colormap, which is given on the `matplotlib` page..

[image]

Comment: Can i customize different colors for different value range?